# Admin stuck on loading when creating a new product

Tags: product, admin

some admin users whatever the role he has. when creating a new simple product Magento stocks loading the page without any HTTP request.

I tried these commands. `setup:upgrade` & `setup:di:compile` & `setup:static-content:deploy` nothing helps

Note: the problem is happening with some users on random devices, not a specific user or a specific device.

Comment: can you check error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please Check below things :

```
- Check broswer console on your network section may be dataprofider will display the error
- please try the below command
  $ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- And it is still same then you can disable your custom module so you can get the issues (Please take the Backup of you DB)
```